# C Code for Python's property function?

Tags: python, c, properties, python-3.x

I am really curious as to **how** Python's interpreter makes an attribute `x` out of a method `x` through `x=property(x)`. If I could take a look at the `C` code, I would feel much better.

Comment: Go ahead then, download Python's source code and have a look

Comment: So go look at it? Here is the [source code](http://www.python.org/getit/source/). Maybe check [this out too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728472/i-want-to-start-reading-the-python-source-code-where-should-i-start)

Comment: Mmm. My hope was (is) that it takes only a couple of lines to define the property fucntion and someone may paste the code :-)))

Comment: It's worth pointing out that, although CPython _does_ special-case properties (since 2.2 or so), it doesn't actually need to; you can write something 100% equivalent in pure Python and it'll work exactly the same (except possibly for performance). Read the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) for an explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type is defined in the [`descrobject.c` file](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/descrobject.c#l1228).

You can locate Python types like these by first looking for the function name in [`bltinmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/bltinmodule.c); in this case the following line defines the `property()` function:

```
SETBUILTIN("property",              &PyProperty_Type);
```

then grep for the `PyProperty_Type` definition in the `Objects` subdirectory.

Comment: Wow. Exactly what I was hoping for.