# How to inspect source code of print

Tags: python, python-2.7, inspect

I can get the source code of a function using `inspect.getsource(obj)`.

```
print(inspect.getsource(gcd))
```

It prints the source code of the `gcd` function. When I try the following, it throws error.

```
>>>print(inspect.getsource(print))

  File "<stdin>", line 1
     print(inspect.getsourcelines(print))
                                 ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can I get the source code of print ?; If yes How?, If no Why?

Comment: No, because `print` is a function, written in C. `inspect` can only get  sources of Python functions.

Comment: You are aware that python is open source and thus the whole source code is available online, right? You can just get it straight from the repository instead of using `inspect` (which throws a syntax error as `print` is a language keyword in python 2, not a function as it is in python 3).

Comment: @l4mpi Ya, I know python is open source. So only I tried to view the source code of print.

Comment: @Martin Pieters It is not a duplicate of that question. I can't get the source code of print. I want to just see the implementation of print not all the in-built functions and I want a reason for that error. How it could be a duplicate of that question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions)

Comment: @Venkatesh I did give you a reason for the error: `print` is a _keyword_ in python2, not just a function name; and thus it can't occur as an argument to anything. The same error would happen if you call `getsource` with any other keyword like `if`, `for`, `with`, `and` etc. And see the duplicate linked by vaultah for how to find the source (the answer by keviarpe specifically). Lastly, here's a link to the c source: https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1569

Comment: I'll ask a different question:  why?  What are you trying to find out about `print`?  By the way, you *can* use the print function in python 2 using the `from __future__ import print_function` but it behaves differently to the `print` statement.

Comment: Also related: [Where builtin functions are implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24723583), [C Code for Python's property function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16447280) and [Python source code for built-in "in" operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12244074)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering to add more information than the dupe target that vaultah provided.

The following answer addresses 3.x directly, I noticed you're still on 2.x.  For a good write-up on that, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244074/python-source-code-for-built-in-in-operator).

You're actually down the right path on this, but the issue is that `print` is a built-in, so `inspect.getsource` won't do you much good here.

Which is to say:

```
>>> inspect.getsource.__doc__
'Return the text of the source code for an object.

The argument may be a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame,    
or code object.  The source code is returned as a single string.  An
OSError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved.'
```

and where as `print` is of `type`:

```
>>> type(print)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

And more specifically:

```
>>> print.__module__
'builtins'
```

how unfortunate, it's not supported by `getsource`.

You have options:

1) Walk through the [Python source code](https://hg.python.org/) and see how your built-in has been implemented.  In my case, I almost always use CPython, so I'd start at the [CPython directory](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/).

Since we know we're hunting for a `builtin` module, we go into the `/Python` dir and look for something that looks like it would contain built-in modules.  `bltinmodule.c` is a safe guess.  Knowing that print has to be defined as a function to be callable, search for `print(` and we hop right to [builtin_print(Pyobject...](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/98376cf9133d/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2190) where it's defined.

2) Make the lucky guess of the built-in function name convention and search for `builtin_print` in the code repo.

3) Use a tool that does the magic behind the scenes, such as Puneeth Chaganti's [Cinspect](https://github.com/punchagan/cinspect).

Comment: Your answer is valid for Python 3.x, but the OP is using Python 2.7, in which `print` is a statement.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yeah, I noticed that after posting.  I have to run to handle something important and will edit later.